# UITableViewCell contentView inset on iPhone X

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, ios11, iphone-x

Any UITableViewCell created on iPhone X has a 44 points inset for content view. This means width of contentView of UITableViewCell is by default 44pts less than the cell width. I do not need to have this behavior. How do I get contentView width same as cell width (or like it is there on other iPhone models)?

Update: I solved the problem by setting tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = NO. Now working on same issue for other elements such as UINavigationBar items. Unable to find an equivalent was for UIBarButtonItem for navigation bar. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use additionalSafeAreaInsets on your view controller, it's there to reduce the actual usable space but with negative Insets it should do the opposite.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2902284-additionalsafeareainsets

Comment: self.navigationController.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -44, 0, -44) works, not the viewController.

Answer (score 0):

In your table view set `insetsContentViewsToSafeArea` to false.

`tableview.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false`